# Listbox data

Tags: c#, listbox

Now in my program in c# that simulates the working of a lan-messenger I need to show the people who are currently online with one remote host-name on each line.
However the problem here is that in order to do that I am using the function

```
//edited this line out, can't find a .Append for listBox or .AppendLine
//listBox.Append(String );

listBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(String));
```

On doing so, the carriage return and new line character(ie.. \r and \n) are being displayed as tiny little rectangular boxes at the end of the hostname. How do I get rid of that?

Comment: Which ListBox are you using?  I don't see an AppendLine method on any of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
listBox.Append(String.Replace("\r\n", ""));
```

to get rid of those characters

Comment: Have you had much luck utilizing the listBox.Append()?

Answer (score 1):

Another option would be to consider creating an extension method for the custom trim that you are trying to achieve.

```
/// <summary>
/// Summary description for Helper
/// </summary>
public static class Helper
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Extension Method For Returning Custom Trim
    /// No Carriage Return or New Lines Allowed
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="str">Current String Object</param>
    /// <returns></returns>
    public static string CustomTrim(this String str)
    {
        return str.Replace("\r\n", "");
    }
}
```

Your line of code then looks like this:

```
listBox.Items.Add(new ListItem(myString.CustomTrim());
```

Comment: Adding such extensions will add lots of junk to medium size+ projects.
Just because you can make extensions don't mean you should.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [Trim](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.trim.aspx) method of the string to remove unwanted characters from the start and end of the string. Either call it without parameters to remove all white-space (including like breaks), or pass a character array with the characters that you want removed.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're using some sort of TextBox in single line mode. If so, activate [TextBox.Multiline](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.textbox.multiline.aspx).